# How to reduce the data rate?(OV7670 + AL422B(FIFO) Camera Module)

Tags: rf, stm32, camera, interface, data

I bought this module: [OV7670 + AL422B(FIFO) Camera Module](http://www.hotmcu.com/ov7670-al422bfifo-camera-modulev20-p-19.html) and I want to send the live video of the camera by this [NRF24L01](http://www.ebay.com/itm/NRF24L01-PA-LNA-SMA-Antenna-Wireless-Transceiver-communication-module-2-4G-G5-/200963287312) but I have several questions.

- Is the RF module suitable(NRF24L01) for this job?
- I think the data rate of the NRF24L01 isn't enough for camera. what's
  your opinion?
- If you agree with me, in your opinion, how can I solve this problem?(in other word, can I reduce the size of the camera's data(video)?)

I should send the video by NRF24L01 for 1Mbps or more. in addition, I'm using STM32F103RET6 for this job.

Comment: Do you have a specific resolution requirement? I doubt that you could maintain a "live" video, but you could transfer frames at a certain rate (lower than 30fps more than likely).

Comment: Try stack exchange/Audio-video production and ask them how to compress a video output suitable for streaming. What the hardware requirements are. Let me know too! http://avp.stackexchange.com/questions

Comment: @GustavoLitovsky No, i think 24fps is suitable.

Comment: @Roh: 24fps is unlikely. What kind of image resolution do you need?

Comment: @GustavoLitovsky i don't know exactly but i can to say that i want to show the video on a N96 LCD(2.8").

Comment: Never mind 2.8", what **resolution** is it?

Comment: So you either want to scale the image to 320x240 or crop a section of it, or both (assuming you can't just configure the camera to output a downsampled image). Doing that at the camera end (before transmission) drops the data rate massively and gives everything else much less work to do.

Comment: @Roh, what have you decided? I am with precisely the same modules (ov7670 + nrf24l01) and trying to do the samething but with a PIC MCU instead. I'm thinking of compressing the image by N in N lines (RAM limitation). Have you got any solution to this task?

Comment: @user2110874 Unfortunately no! I think we have to choose a faster MCU(or maybe DSP) with a bigger RAM and a faster module. seem no way(sad)

Comment: I am thinking of this:

http://www.microchip.com/wwwproducts/Devices.aspx?dDocName=en559066

A 1Mbit SRAM to put the frames so a MCU can compress the data and than send it through nrf24l01. Since the module data rate is not so fast, I think any 40MIPS MCU can do the trick (it's only a guess). Then instead of 600k image we will have something around 40k (jpeg format).

Comment: @user2110874 Anyway I think the 40MIPS is low. maybe 120 will be suitable because you can't do other job(finally you just can send the video). it's not bad for a quadcopter! :-)

Comment: It's exaclty what I am using too (quadcopter). But still, maybe a dedicated 40 MIPS only for compression is ok, dont you think? Because I think you dont really need to compress in the same speed of the maximum camera data output rate. The true limitation of the system will be the nrf24l01. Maybe in a rate of 3~5 fps should be possible. It depends on wheter this fps rate is ok for you...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you can sustain the maximum datarate for the nRF24L01 ([2 megabits persecond](http://www.nordicsemi.com/eng/Products/2.4GHz-RF/nRF24L01)), then that means you can move — in a perfect world — 200 kilobytes per second (assuming no overhead).

So given this, and your desired minimum of 24fps, you can calculate just how many bytes you need each image to be: `200K / 24 = 8.53K` per frame

Now you haven't said what resolution you want, but the maximum resolution of the ov7670 is 640x480, and it uses 16bits per pixel (it is a little more complicated than that, I invite the curious to read the [Data Sheet](http://www.voti.nl/docs/OV7670.pdf)).

As our calculators all know `640 * 480 * 2 = 614,400` Bytes — 72 times that 8.53K per frame.  In fact it would take in the ballpark of 3 seconds per frame (6 seconds if running at 1mbps).

**So to answer your first two questions:** The nRF24L01 isn't up to the task of transmitting live 640x480 video.

So this leaves us with your third question: **How do reduce the size of the cameras data?**

There are (*not* mutually exclusive) three ways  of doing this:

1. Compress the images
2. Compress the data
3. Send smaller images

Let us break each of these down:

**Compress the images**

You could, for example, send the images as a M-JPEG stream.  This would certainly make decoding the images on the phone side much easier, and would reduce the size of the images sent quite a bit.

But there is one problem: You need to be able to hold the whole image in memory in order to do JPEG (and thus M-JPEG) compression.  Your ST32F103RET6 has 64K of RAM (IIRC), so there is no way it is going to fit.  And I am not sure of a lossy compression scheme you could use that doesn't need the whole image at once.

**Compress the data**

Now there are a number of options you could do here: Huffman, Run Length Encoding, LWZ, etc.  Unfortunately none of these are going to produce a predictable amount of compression.  It is going to depend on the images you send.

But I think it is safe to say you aren't going to get the 8.53K you would need for 24fps.

**Send smaller images**

The OV7670 is rather flexible when it comes to resolutions.  So let us take a look at some other resolutions you could use:

- QVGA (320x240): `320 * 240 * 2 = 150K` per frame.  At this rate you could send just over 1fps
- QQVGA (160x120): `160 * 120 * 2 = 37K` per frame.  This is the first image size you could store entirely in RAM
- QQQVGA (80x60): `80 * 60 * 2 = 9.38K` per frame. With compression you should be able to do 24fps video
- QQQQVGA (40x30): `40 * 30 * 2 = 2.35K per frame.  At this (postage stamp) of a size you could steam at 30fps 1mbps!  I believe this is the lowest resolution supported by the camera.

QQVGA may be possible if you do very lossy JPEG compression, and then do some compression on the data stream as well.  You are going to have to experiment to be sure.

**A Postscript**

You are going to be hard pressed to find a faster wireless technology than the nRF24L01 (and its ilk), without going to wifi (for example the [Adafruit CC3000 Module](http://www.adafruit.com/products/1510)).  With that, a microcontroller with a LOT of ram, and compression, you should be able to stream 24-30fps.

Alternately there are camera driver chips that do the JPEG compression for you — the vc0706 for example.  With that attached to a camera, and using the vc0706's SPI link you should then be able to use even a trivial microcontroller to transmit the data.

I have yet to meet a camera module with vc0706 that exposes the SPI pins, they are all serial.  One may exist, but I haven't found it yet.  So if you go down this route, you may have to do it yourself...

Comment: I've been working with nRFs a LOT recently. There us **no** way you're even going to get close to 2 Mbps. A few hundred kbps is probably about the best you could possibly hope for, and that would be with all the automatic retransmit mechanisms turned off.

Comment: Which nRFs have you been using? There are three operating ranges, different antenna types, and then distance.  Speed and performance are the factor of multiple variables.  But I picked 2Mbps because it was the theoretical maximum, and thus the best you could possibly get to show just how small each frame has to be even then.  The math scales so you can simply adjust the numbers for different speeds

Comment: *"But there is one problem: You need to be able to hold the whole image in memory in order to do JPEG (and thus M-JPEG) compression. Your ST32F103RET6 has 64K of RAM (IIRC), so there is no way it is going to fit. And I am not sure of a lossy compression scheme you could use that doesn't need the whole image at once."* Perhaps you can compress the image to JPEG using this microcontroller with limited RAM by using jpegant. It's designed for JPEG compression in MCUs: https://sourceforge.net/projects/jpegant/

Comment: @John3348 The problem is that you would need a pixel addressable image source, because encoding JPEG requires that you can either have the entire frame in memory or can get arbitrary pixels; since it uses a zigzag scan pattern.  The camera in question provides a linear bitstream so you would have to hold the frame in memory.  PNG can compress a linear bitstream, but being lossless would not be able to get down to that 37K per frame needed for 30FPS in all sitations

Comment: @John3348 Also a quick examination of jpegant shows that while it is quite memory efficient, it does require access to the full original